# SwiftUI onDrop not triggered on part of HStack with Spacer

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project where I have an HStack containing a Spacer and a Rectangle. The onDrop modifier is set on the HStack to handle drop events, but I've encountered an issue where the onDrop event is not triggered when the cursor is over the Spacer.

I've verified that there are no overlapping views or views with higher z-index values that could be blocking the Spacer. Additionally, the Spacer is not disabled and has no modifiers preventing user interactions.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```swift
HStack() {
    Spacer()
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground))
        .frame(width: 3)
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 22)
.background(.clear)
.foregroundColor(i == iS && j == jS && isInsertS == true ? .yellow : Color(.systemBackground))
.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], delegate: ButtonDropDelegate(/*...*/))
```

I expect the onDrop event to be triggered for the entire HStack, including the Spacer. However, it only works when the cursor is over the Rectangle, and the drop event is not recognized when the cursor is over the Spacer.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a limitation in SwiftUI's hit-testing mechanism? Has anyone encountered a similar issue with onDrop not being triggered on certain parts of a HStack containing a Spacer?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```swift
struct ButtonDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let ruleEditorRow: RuleEditorRow
    let keyword: RuleEditorColumn
    let sharedState: SharedState
    let i: Int
    let j: Int
    let isInsert: Bool
    @Binding var iS: Int?
    @Binding var jS: Int?
    @Binding var isInsertS: Bool?
    
    init(ruleEditorRow: RuleEditorRow, keyword: RuleEditorColumn, sharedState: SharedState, i: Int, j: Int, isInsert: Bool, iS: Binding<Int?>, jS: Binding<Int?>, isInsertS: Binding<Bool?>) {
        self.ruleEditorRow = ruleEditorRow
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.sharedState = sharedState
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.isInsert = isInsert
        self._iS = iS
        self._jS = jS
        self._isInsertS = isInsertS
    }
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        
        sharedState.dragStarted = false
        
        // ..
        
        return true
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        iS = nil
        jS = nil
        isInsertS = nil
        
        print("iS: \(iS) jS: \(jS) isInsertS: \(isInsertS)")
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        iS = i
        jS = j
        isInsertS = isInsert
        
        print("iS: \(iS) jS: \(jS) isInsertS: \(isInsertS)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce on macOS 13.3.1.

Comment: I have Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)